# Django on Heroku : Application Error

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.7, heroku

I'm trying to run an existing git Django project on Heroku. Doesn't seem to be working. I'll post the logs. Any ideas what the issue is?

There was an error before with collect_static, but I'm not sure if that is the main issue with this.

```
C:\Django\campusarchitect>heroku logs
2017-02-18T19:25:20.432194+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:25:20.585437+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:25:20.432194+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:25:20.601060+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:25:20.585437+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:25:20.685280+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:26:02.680411+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-18T19:27:27.383189+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-18T19:32:18.057971+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-18T19:35:18.091254+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-18T19:36:13.149054+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:36:13.149054+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:36:13.345418+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:37:11.776702+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:37:11.776702+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-curly-36955) by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:37:12.395622+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-18T19:37:12.395628+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-02-18T19:37:12.211277+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:37:12.211277+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 43da54b by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:37:12.415876+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:37:35.187380+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=10bfc523-f737-4224-86bd-e7319b9ab34c fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:37:37.123921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=58458ca8-8295-41d1-98eb-7a9c49ce99f0 fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:37:46.114419+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=cacdc865-4535-44f4-bcdc-bdaaff845f12 fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:37:46.812011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=5978f6c6-fdfe-4f56-9f33-2c2b0e717c7e fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:41:06.527357+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-18T19:41:06.527367+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-02-18T19:41:06.396796+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 64fc3ff by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:41:06.396796+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:41:06.847267+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:44:07.978545+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=f4283f97-0940-4997-a821-7712723fa1f9 fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:44:09.893035+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=da3aec49-8954-4644-ac17-516b06acf857 fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:44:43.745167+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:44:43.925649+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-18T19:44:43.925655+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-02-18T19:44:43.745167+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3ce00d3 by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:44:44.236888+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:45:09.499220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=e01e0e36-4e31-458d-923e-da65c6ed1a7b fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:45:11.525184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=f29baed0-aece-4327-b7f7-81ca0219fa5e fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:47:33.854691+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:47:33.854691+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:47:33.985146+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:48:07.400086+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user bradleymitchellis@gmail.com
2017-02-18T19:48:12.256784+00:00 heroku[run.9812]: Awaiting client
2017-02-18T19:48:12.293106+00:00 heroku[run.9812]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2017-02-18T19:48:12.444593+00:00 heroku[run.9812]: State changed from starting to up
2017-02-18T19:48:17.637861+00:00 heroku[run.9812]: Process exited with status 1
2017-02-18T19:48:17.853541+00:00 heroku[run.9812]: State changed from up to complete
2017-02-18T19:48:42.251644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=077c3a7f-4c4e-4cc1-80e5-585232d03b01 fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T19:48:42.696538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-brook-86729.herokuapp.com request_id=4abe6937-40a1-406d-b739-df7246fe6622 fwd="192.76.177.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: What does your Procfile look like?

Comment: Have you enabled the resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can look the error cade from [Heroku Error Codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes) .

at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

This is most likely the result of scaling your web dynos down to 0 dynos. To fix it, scale your web dynos to 1 or more dynos:
`heroku ps:scale web=1`

You have to let web on.